# How can I increase the font size in Html.fromHtml?

Tags: android, html, android-studio, fromhtml

> This code shows a View window, and displays a text document in HTML
> format.
>  I think the function is clear so:
>  All colors and formats work,
> but the font all comes in a default size and is rather small.
> -I want to customize the font size.
> -And I want to customize the background color of the page as well.
>
> If there are other additions that can improve the presentation, I
> would be grateful to you

```
    Button btn_azkar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_azkar);
    btn_azkar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            help();
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void help() {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("azkar.txt");
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
                BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                String line;
                StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();
                while ((line = BR.readLine()) != null) {
                    msg.append(line + "\n");
                }
                AlertDialog.Builder build = new AlertDialog.Builder(Info_Activity.this);
                build.setTitle(R.string.azkar);
            //  build.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
                build.setMessage(Html.fromHtml(msg + ""));
                build.setNegativeButton(R.string.dilog_close, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Negative
                    }
                }).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Should be able to find an example if you search the API Documentation. I can't find it so easily myself because you didn't show the import for the Html class. Could you provide the relevant import?

Answer (score 1):

> I found a temporary solution and it enlarges the font size of the
> layout completely:
>  So I fixed the font size of the buttons by `dp` and
> incremented: `fontScale = 1.2f;`. I got good results and am waiting for
> a better solution.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(newBase);
        Configuration config = new Configuration(newBase.getResources().getConfiguration());
        config.fontScale = 1.2f;
        applyOverrideConfiguration(config);
    }
```